# iPhone UIAutomation button tap does not fire

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios4, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to use UIAutomation in Instruments with the iPhone Simulator and the latest iOS SDK 4.1.  Here is the snippet of javascript that is having a problem:

```
// there are sufficient delays here to make sure the view is loaded
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().logElementTree();
main.buttons()["theButton"].tap();
UIALogger.logMessage("The button tapped");
for (var b = 0; b < main.buttons().length; b++)
{
    UIALogger.logMessage("Button title: " + main.buttons()[b].name());
}
main.toolbar().buttons()["OK"].tap();
UIALogger.logMessage("OK tapped");
```

The button name of "theButton" shows up in the logElementTree as well as showing up when I am logging the names of all the buttons, so it is correctly configured in the Interface Builder, but for some reason, it does not get tapped.  I have other buttons earlier in the script that are getting tapped just fine, and if I abort the script at the point of the non-tapped button, I can click on the button in the Simulator and it works as expected.

EDIT: In the javascript for loop shown above, I had it tap each of the buttons in the main.buttons() array, and only 1 of the 12 identical buttons on the view gets the tap.

Also, in case you were wondering, I have this code at the top of the javascript file:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var main = app.mainWindow();
```

And here is the line that shows the button information from the sequence of entries that logElementTree puts into the log messages:

```
4) UIAButton [name:theButton value:(null) NSRect: {{25, 93}, {74, 74}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with tapping a button on an actionSheet. I'm performing the scripts on the actual device.
My code is:

```
//check that action sheet is on the screen
    app.actionSheetIsValid();

//check that the button is on the actionSheet
    actionSheet.actionSheetButton("Exit");

//touch Exit button
    actionSheet.tapActionSheetButtonByName("Exit");
```

All functions perform and pass, however the button is not pressed.
`logElementTree();` shows that the button is there.

I tried to add `target.pushTimeout(5);` after I check that the button is on the actionSheet in order to give it some time to detect and tap the button. This didn't help.

Then I added: `target.delay(1);` right after I check that the button is on the actionSheet and before tapping it.
It helped in my case, the script is more robust and stable now.

Comment: I tried to nudge the button to make sure it is still there, I put in a delay of at least 1 second before the button tap, and I still get nothing on the main window button tap.  I did a logElement on the button and it shows up with the same description as it did above, and the OK toolbar button tap works well.  What do you have going on in your actionSheetIsValid, actionSheetButton, and tapActionSheetButtonByName functions?  Thanks.  BP